# ServletException when accessing Cron tab on Capedwarf

Tags: java, jboss, capedwarf

Error when accessing Cron tab on Capedwarf Admin:

```
10:23:52,284 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-74) UT005023: Exception handling request to /_ah/admin/cronJobs.vm: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.jboss.capedwarf.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'getJobs' in  class org.jboss.capedwarf.admin.CronJobs$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException at /org/jboss/capedwarf/admin/cronJobs.vm[line 17, column 33]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.admin.AdminServlet.service(AdminServlet.java:76) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:129) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.appidentity.GAEFilter.doFilter(GAEFilter.java:62) [capedwarf-appidentity-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_163]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_163]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_163]
Caused by: org.jboss.capedwarf.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'getJobs' in  class org.jboss.capedwarf.admin.CronJobs$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException at /org/jboss/capedwarf/admin/cronJobs.vm[line 17, column 33]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIdentifier.execute(ASTIdentifier.java:223) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:262) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:507) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.Foreach.render(Foreach.java:282) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTDirective.render(ASTDirective.java:175) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:336) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:328) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:235) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.admin.AdminServlet.serveVelocityPage(AdminServlet.java:97) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.admin.AdminServlet.service(AdminServlet.java:71) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.TimeZone.parseCustomTimeZone(TimeZone.java:783) [rt.jar:1.8.0_163]
    at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:562) [rt.jar:1.8.0_163]
    at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:516) [rt.jar:1.8.0_163]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.admin.CronJobs.create(CronJobs.java:69) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.admin.CronJobs.access$000(CronJobs.java:43) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.admin.CronJobs$Job.createNext(CronJobs.java:90) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.admin.CronJobs$Job.<init>(CronJobs.java:86) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.admin.CronJobs.getJobs(CronJobs.java:62) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.admin.CronJobs$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getJobs(Unknown Source) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_163]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_163]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_163]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_163]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.PropertyExecutor.execute(PropertyExecutor.java:142) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelGetterImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:533) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.capedwarf.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIdentifier.execute(ASTIdentifier.java:198) [capedwarf-admin-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 44 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have timezone specified in your cron.xml

Comment: It worked. I never actually knew that is was required. Thanks @alesj

Comment: I don't think it's required -- if none is specified, it should be GMT. But it looks like I missed this in the UI layer -- it's there for the actual cron execution.